# Why would WordPress request FTP information when it can write to the file server?

Tags: plugins, ftp

I don't think this is a duplicate, although I've seen similar questions on here.

I have added my primary SSH/FTP user and the user `nobody` to a group called `webserver`, then I ran a `chown -R .webserver /var/www` so that both FTP and Apache would be able to write to the file system.

I know that PHP can write to the server -- I can upload an image using the Media Library. However, when I go to install a plugin, it prompts me for my FTP credentials.

If I add `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to wp-config.php, this goes away and plugins install without an issue.

Why would this happen, though? According to the Codex, the preferred method is direct, and it's *able* to manipulate the file system directly. So what would make it prompt for FTP instead?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I took a look at the source for how it determines what file system method to use (`wp-admin/includes/file.php`, line 933), and I figured out that it can create a test file, but the owner does not match the processor's UID. Taking a look at the PHP manual for `getmyuid()` and `fileowner($file)`, it seems that, instead of using `getmyuid()`, it *should* be using `posix_getuid()`. Any idea why the developers would use the former?

**EDIT 2**:

Noted in WordPress bug tracker: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10205

Answer (score 3):

[Posix](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.posix.php) is a PHP extension rather than part of PHP core. WordPress tries to minimize use of extensions as much as possible in its core. In specific case of Posix one — it has very notable flaw of not being available on Windows platform altogether.