# Why can I upload files but need FTP login for plugins

Tags: permissions

I know this is probably a file permission issue, but I can't figure out why it's happening. (I'm more trying to understand what's going on rather than looking for a quick fix.)

Why would I be able to upload media, but not update or install plugins?  My `wp-content` folder and even `plugins` folders look to have the correct permissions. Apache server runs under `www-data` and that group has ownership of the folders and files.

```
drwxrwsr-x  6 www-data www-data  4096 Apr  2 21:40 wp-content
drwxrwsr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  2 21:15 plugins
```

Note: I did read [Why would WordPress request FTP information when it can write to the file server?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145530/why-would-wordpress-request-ftp-information-when-it-can-write-to-the-file-server) but I'm still not completely understanding what's going on.

Note2: This is on a VPS not shared.

Comment: strange, not sure but in my experience a mismatch *somewhere* can be enough... sometimes resetting *all* the permissions recursively has fixed this for me, eg. `chown -R www-data:www-data public_html` ...worth a try?

Comment: looks like that did the trick!  If you want to add it as a solution I'll make it as the answer.

Comment: great it did it. i've added a more elaborate answer for future reference then, :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an owner/group mismatch in just one of the directories or subdirectories of your install can be enough to make `WP_Filesystem` see that the permissions don't match and ask for your FTP details instead.

eg. I have had this when copying/installing a plugin as `root` user via SSH, forgot about setting the owner/group, and then then plugin won't update directly later without fixing them.

You could try to track down those permissions and change them individually, but a good overall and fast solution to try is to simply update the owner/group permissions of your entire install recursively (from the level below `public_html` or your install root.) This has the added bonus of fixing any other permissions you may have forgot to fix too:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data public_html
```

Where `www-data` is your "web" user (will not be the same for everyone. eg. admin, apache)

Note this is a slightly shortcut method that is also the same as setting owner and group separately:

```
chown -R www-data public_html
chgrp -R www-data public_html
```